# Ember App Deployed to Heroku Isn't Loading Data from REST API

Tags: ember.js

Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm having a strange problem with a simple Ember app where, after deploying to Heroku, my models only make the REST call after the index route for the model is hit.

For example, I have two models: `Resort` and `Forecast`. Each have a `belongsTo` relationship, so every `Resort` has a `Forecast` and vice versa. In the resort template, there's a link to the corresponding forecast. When clicked, it properly routes to the forecast, however all the attributes in the forecast are undefined because it never made the API call to retrieve the forecasts JSON blob. I can watch the network tab in Chrome tools to verify this. When I navigate to `/forecasts`, the REST call is made, and the data is populated.

For whatever reason, all the API calls are made as I would expect. Once deployed to Heroku, this isn't the case.

This app is using ember-cli, and the relevant code follows:

/adapters/application.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://api.firstchair.io',

  buildURL: function() {
    var base;
    base = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    return "" + base + ".json";
  }
});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

/models/resort.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('string'),
  latitude: DS.attr('string'),
  longitude: DS.attr('string'),
  region: DS.attr('string'),
  token: DS.attr('string'),
  weather: DS.attr('string'),
  temperature: DS.attr('string'),
  last_24_hours_snowfall: DS.attr('string'),
  last_48_hours_snowfall: DS.attr('string'),
  last_72_hours_snowfall: DS.attr('string'),
  wind: DS.attr('string'),
  conditions: DS.attr('string'),
  baseDepth: DS.attr('string'),
  humanReadableWeather: DS.attr('string'),

  forecast: DS.belongsTo('forecast'),

  fullDescription: function() {
    return this.get('name') + ', ' + this.get('state');
  }.property('name', 'state'),

  currentSnowfall: function() {
    return (this.get('last_24_hours_snowfall') || 0) + '"';
  }.property('last_24_hours_snowfall'),

  hasWind: function() {
    return this.get('wind') > 0;
  }.property('wind')
});
```

/models/forecast.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  startsAt: DS.attr('string'),
  endsAt: DS.attr('string'),
  weather: DS.attr('array'),
  highs: DS.attr('array'),
  lows: DS.attr('array'),

  resort: DS.belongsTo('resort'),

  days: function() {
    var weather = this.get('weather');
    var highs = this.get('highs');
    var lows = this.get('lows');

    if (!weather) { return []; }

    return weather.map(function(currWeather, index) {
      return {
        weather: currWeather,
        high: highs[index],
        low: lows[index],
        daysSince: index
      };
    });
  }.property('weather', 'highs', 'lows')
});
```

/routes/resort.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var resort = this.store.find('resort', params.resort_id);
    console.log(resort);
    console.log(resort.forecast);
    return resort;
  }
});
```

/routes/resorts.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('resort');
  }
});
```

/routes/forecast.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log('hello');
    return this.store.find('forecast', params.forecast_id);
  }
});
```

/routes/forecasts.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('forecast');
  }
});
```

Is there something I should be doing to ensure that the data is loaded eagerly?

You can look at the code in its entirety at: https://github.com/firstchair-io/webapp

Any insight into what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How does the backend serialize the relationship? If the referenced records are not sideloaded by the API try setting `{async:true}` on your relationships.

Comment: Thanks, @Baruch! That was exactly it. Do you have any idea as to why it was only required in production? Does development somehow eager load while production doesn't? Also, if you'd like to make this an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: Great. I can't speak to the difference between production and development without knowing more about the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the relationships are not being sideloaded from the backend server. So the records contain an array of ID's in the `hasMany` fields, but the data itself is not sent automatically. To cause Ember Data to load the associated records, set `{async: true}` on the relation.